# Checkout new branch at old commit and push new branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, push, branch, git-checkout

I am checking out a new branch at a previous commit using the following command:

`git checkout -b new-branch <commit-hash>`

This switches me to the new branch at this commit, but how can I push it?

I've tried pushing it and setting the remote as upstream using this:

`git push --set-upstream origin new-branch`

But nothing gets pushed; all that happens is the local branch is set up to track the remote one. How can I push this old commit on this new branch without making any other changes?

Comment: Did you want to push `upstream` or `origin`? What output do you get from git?

Comment: What output or other observation is leading you to believe the push wasn't completed?  This works fine in my tests.  From phrasing, I wonder if you're confused about what it means to push a branch pointing at history that's already on the server.  You don't really "push the commit to the branch"; you just tell the server to (if necessary create the branch ref and then) point the branch ref to the commit it already has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What made me think that the push wasn't completed was through Bitbucket's GUI in which the branch wasn't appearing under `Active`. I switched the tab to `Merged` and found my branch at the correct commit.